# How to stop Android apps starting automatically when internet connect?

Tags: applications, background-data

How to stop Android apps (such as "todoist") starting automatically when internet connect?
(non-root device)

Comment: That's how these apps keep their data in sync. What are you trying to achieve by stopping them running?

Answer (score 1):

You can go to the app info screen (Settings > Apps [> App List] > Select App) then click on Data Usage. This provides a number of options to control its access to network.

You do need Android 5.0 or up I think.[image: android App Info]

[image: Android app data usage controls]